# The font 'AppleColorEmoji' contains bad / Widths

Tags: macos, pdf, adobe-acrobat, unicode, character-encoding

I'm trying to add an emoji in my email signature. I've copy/pasted if from a site listing all emojis. It displays fine in all the clients I've tried to open my emails with:

[image]

But, when I try to save my email in PDF (using the Print function in Gmail or Office 365) and open it with Acrobat, I get this error:

[image]

What's going on? Why 'AppleColorEmoji'? I'm not on iOS. I even tried to copy/paste the emoji from a few other sites but I got the same message when opening the PDF.

Comment: On OS X, as well as on iOS, the font Apple Color Emoji is used to display emoji characters across the system.

Comment: So it's a bug of Acrobat?

Comment: Not necessarily. I assume it's a problem with the font, which most software ignores, but Acrobat is particularly picky about. Do you get it with any other PDF files of emoji? Try opening a PDF made by exporting a Pages/Word document in Acrobat, and see if the same problem occurs.

Comment: If i remember correctly this is an Adobe reader/Acrobat bug